# I would like to move a picture where I want

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

[image]

I just wanna do what is in the right of the pic

what i wrote so far to move this pic :

```
\begin{right}

\hfill\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{phone-gone.png}

\end{right}
```

Comment: There is no such environment like `right`, please add some compilable code that replicates the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: You should explain better that are these two black boxes (two paragraphs of the same text ? independent text minipages?) the first one should be aligned with the image? Are you using a document with one or two column?  etc. The MWE will help to us to  understand what are you trying really without too much verbosity and will help to propose a solution. BTW,  it seems that that you are searching  for the `wrapfig`  package or maybe the `tufte` classes.